Golang Marshalling a struct that contains both structs and protobuf
I need to marshal a golang struct to JSON. The struct contains many deeply nested objects. Some of these nested objects are regular structs, while others are protobuf proto.Message objects. The protos are defined in a separate package.
For the regular structs, I want to mashal them using the built-in golang json.Marshal function. For the protobufs, I want to marshal them using protojson.Marshal.
Is there a way to do this? I know that I can override the MarshalJson method on a per-object basis, but I'm not sure if there's a way to override it for every nested object.

Probably not what you want to hear, but is it possible to model the outer struct as a proto?

Depending on the proto types used, you might be able to get away with just using encoding/json, especially if it's just for diagnostics.

@coxley I could model the outer struct as a proto, but the contained objects are from a mix of sources, and are not all protos.

@coxley I need to display enums as their string representation, which is why I need protojson

I haven't tried it, but this might be promising: https://github.com/mitchellh/protoc-gen-go-json - it can generate extra marshalers/unmarshalers for the proto types themselves that use protojson under the hood.
